# What does this error means: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pos' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I'm working at a project in Sublime using Python, trying to make a snake game and it keeps giving me this error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pos' referenced before assignment".I've searched for an answer on other forums but couldn't find anything helpful. May u guys help me please
There is the code that I've done so far:

```
import turtle
import time
import random
global pos


delay = 0.1


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake")
wn.bgcolor("purple")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)

head=turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("orange")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "stop"

def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)


    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y - 20)


    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x - 20)


    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)


food = turtle.Turtle()
food.speed(0)
food.shape("circle")
food.color("green")
food.penup()
food.goto(-110, 70)

def ball_move():
    if head.distance("food")<20:
        x = random.randit(-290, 290)
        y = random.randit(-290, 290)
        food.goto(x, y)



def go_up():
    head.direction = "up"

def go_down():
    head.direction = "down"

def go_left():
    head.direction = "left"

def go_right():
    head.direction = "right"


wn.listen()
wn.onkey(go_up, "Up")

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(go_down, "Down")

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(go_left, "Left")

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(go_right, "Right")



while True:
    wn.update()
    move()
    ball_move()
    time.sleep(delay)


turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the line 'global pos' from your file? You don't seem to be using that variable anywhere anyway.

Comment: You haven't defined pos, but calling global on it. Global should only be used when you need to modify outside current scope (should not be used outside a function).

Answer (score 0):

The complete error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 88, in <module>
    ball_move()
  File "test3.py", line 51, in ball_move
    if head.distance("food")<20:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1858, in distance
    return abs(pos - self._position)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pos' referenced before assignment
```

points to the problem which is this line:

```
if head.distance("food")<20:
```

The `distance()` method expects a position or another turtle as an argument, not a string.  In your code, it should read:

```
if head.distance(food) < 20:
```

Which, once fixed, immediately fails with your next error:

`random.randit()` -> `random.randint()`